# Python pymysql if variable is None: logic not working

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm trying to use the nonetype Python logic to determine whether an if statement should run. However, the if statement runs even when the variables equal "None".

```
for row in rows:
    serialnum = row[0]
    lat       = str(row[1])
    lng       = str(row[2])
    if lat is None:
         print "none"
    else:
         print serialnum + " lat: " + lat + " long: " + lng
         jsonfile.write(
            '   {\n'
            '     "name": "' + serialnum + '",\n'
            '     "url": "campaigndetails.php?serial=' + serialnum + '",\n'
            '     "lat": ' + lat + ',\n'
            '     "lng": ' + lng + '\n'
            '   },\n'
        )
```

The lat, lng and serialnum values are all pulled from a MySQL query. Everything is proper, but the logic for the if statement allows for writing to the file even when lat == None

.

What am I missing?

Comment: As a side note, why are you generating JSON manually instead of just creating a dict and using `json.dumps`?

Comment: It could be ignorance, but i'm using a query to generate a file for an OpenStreetMaps instance. I found there that "None" does not jive with JSON here.

I'll take your tip and look into that approach. Thanks.

Comment: If you encode a `None` value with JSON, you get a JSON `null`, which should work just fine on the other side. And if it doesn't, you can transform it in the original data structure and `json.dumps` anyway. There's really no reason to write custom JSON string formatting unless you have a broken client that cares about order or something else that isn't part of valid JSON in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lat = str(row[1])` can never be None because it's a str, so it could be 'None' perhaps

Comment: Or, better, check whether it's `None` _before_ converting it to a `str`.

Comment: @abamert agreed, I was not suggesting testing for string equality, or I didn't mean to, I was just observing what value it might actually hold in that test

Comment: Anyway, this explains his problem; if he doesn't understand from here how to fix it, he can follow up.

Comment: Using both 'None' as the test and testing without converting to string (using a separate variable) yield the same result. Thanks.

Comment: What value is it printing for `lat` in the `else` block then?  I don't know what `row` is, so I can't offer too much specific advice on that front

Comment: Right, sorry for not posting all the background...

When it prints the value of lat in the instance where it is None it prints "None"  (no quotes).

Comment: Alright, well if it prints `None`, but your test for string None (using `==` not `is` right?) or the `None` object doesn't pass, I'm not sure what's happening right now

Comment: I just noobed... when I added the variable that didn't convert to string I forgot to remove the single quotes ('). I got caught up in all your rapid responses and didn't test properly. Thanks!